# Correct way to replace the noun

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality-in-context

1) She had very strong ideas about the kind of company she enjoyed and the one she didn’t.

1) She had very strong ideas about the kind of company she enjoyed and the kind she didn’t.

Are both correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Both are correct, but the first one is a narrower statement. It really singles out one company only for criticism. The second has her admitting to not enjoying multiple companies.

Comment: As you can see from the answer below and Robusto's comment, it depends on what you mean. As a general statement, I would have anticipated "kind...kind."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One* doesn't work as a pronoun for *kind* unless context overwhelmingly is something about one kind in a vast or large array or group of kinds.

> I have 80 kinds of candy.  Which one would be your favorite?

In your example ...

> She had very strong ideas about the kind of company she enjoyed and the one she didn’t.

you set the context to one type of kind by saying *the kind* (even though this picks "one kind" out of every possible kind, it does not choose one among a previously context-established group of kinds)  So it sounds like you mean something else other than *kind* by the subsequent *one*.